# unable to get source code of page aspx webpages

Tags: c#, web-crawler

Im trying to get source code of the page but some pages im not able to get source code through  C# code im using

here is my code

```
      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            string html = client.DownloadString("http://www.acusports.com/roster.aspx?roster=154&path=baseball");
            html = textBox1.Text;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @sethflowers im getting empty value in html

Comment: @KadeKM unable to get source code to write into textbox.

Comment: See the two answers. You are overwriting your html variable. In C#, the value you are assigning from is in the right of the equal sign, and the variable you are assigning the value to is on the left of the equal.

Comment: if i change url to google.com its working but for the url acusports.com/roster.aspx?roster=154&path=baseball its not working.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you switch the following statement:

```
html = textBox1.Text;
```

to this:

```
textBox1.Text = html;
```

In your code, you are setting the `html` string to whatever you retrieve, and then you are immediately overwriting it with the value of `textBox1.Text`.

Comment: if i change url to http://www.google.com its working but for the url http://www.acusports.com/roster.aspx?roster=154&path=baseball its not working.

Comment: The acusports webserver might be checking the user-agent or some other value sent, and sending a response based on it. If you want to emulate your browser, I'd suggest getting a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and inspecting a request from your browser, and then building up a request in code that matches your browser request.

Answer (score 0):

didn't you want to write:

```
textBox1.Text = html;
```